# Missing app windows in Ubuntu when connecting via Google Remote Desktop

Tags: 19.04, remote-desktop

I am using Google Remote Desktop to connect to Ubuntu machine from Windows machine. Everything works fine except the fact that I cannot see opened apps/terminals (those that I have opened on my Ubuntu machine when physically working on it) when using the google remote desktop.

So, I am running a terminal process on my Ubuntu which takes very long and I have it visible on my Ubuntu desktop at all times so that I can monitor its progress. But when I connect to that Ubuntu machine via Google Remote Desktop - I cannot see it/find it anywhere, yet I can see in the system monitor it is running completely fine and doing its thing - I just cannot see the terminal associated with that process when using remote access.

So the question is: how can I make my opened terminals appear when connecting via remote desktop?

Comment: I have not used Google remote desktop for a while. I think it opens a new session when you use the "remotely connect to your computer" option. If you want to open the existing local session, you have to use the "share your desktop someone remotely" option.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I did. When you're connecting via Google remote Desktop you're prompted with 2 options: 1) create Xsession ( = new session as you said) --- 2) Existing Ubuntu Session (= your desktop appears as on the original machine). I never paid attention to that message and always chose default, which is the Xsession.  So thank you, you answered my question!

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help. However, you should write your own answer (below, where it says **Your Answer**) with the details of the 2 options. Provide screenshots if you can. Finally, accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark and make it green. This will help others with the same problem.